# Why do my Next and Previous Buttons look odd on IOS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I'm currently redesigning my website and for this, I have created a carrousel of images and for this, I have used next and previous buttons. On Windows and Andriod they look normal (first image below) but on IOS they become all squished and look a bit weird. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Also sometimes when I am testing out the buttons and I press the previous button it takes the user to the bottom of the page... Is there anything I can do to fix this as well? If you want to have a look for yourself a URL for one of the pages is https://www.fredsfashionboutique.com/valentino-moon-dust-t-shirt.html

[image]

[image]

Below is the JS code that I have used for the Carousel which I got off W3schools. I don't know how to code in JS which is the reason I got it off W3Schools so have tried my best to work with it - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

```html
                    <button class="next" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
                    <button class="previous" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>

                    
                  </div>
                  
                  <script>
                  var slideIndex = 1;
                  showDivs(slideIndex);
                  
                  function plusDivs(n) {
                    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
                  }
                  
                  function showDivs(n) {
                    var i;
                    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
                    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
                    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                      x[i].style.display = "none";  
                    }
                    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                  }
                  </script>
            </div>
```

Here is the CSS code that I used for the previous and next button

```html
      .next{
        background-color: lightgray;
        color: black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
  
    .previous{
      background-color: lightgray;
      color: black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      font-size: 20px;
      }
```

This is also a screen recording of the previous button taking the user to the bottom of the page https://vimeo.com/user24572931/review/441815395/0a41442177

Any help would be much appreciated!
Freddie

Answer (score 1):

You should give it a width and height.

```
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
```

Comment: Yes this worked - thank you! I'm going to leave the question open for a little while just to see if anyone can help with the previous button taking the user to the bottom of the page. But if not I'll mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: I can't reproduce that. What browser and device are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome but it also happens on my Android and my iPhone. The weird thing is that it's not all the time only some of the times. It happens when you press next a few times and then try and press the previous button after.

Answer (score 1):

So its me again (Same as other answer) and I made some changes to your html and css so now its more "future proof" and simple

HTML:

```
          <button class="next btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"></button>
            <button class="previous btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)"></button>

            
          </div>
          
          <script>
          var slideIndex = 1;
          showDivs(slideIndex);
          
          function plusDivs(n) {
            showDivs(slideIndex += n);
          }
          
          function showDivs(n) {
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
            if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
              x[i].style.display = "none";  
            }
            x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
          }
          </script>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn{
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.next:after {
  content: "❮";
}

.previous:after {
  content: "❯";
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I will make those changes now :)

Comment: also you can remove .html from your links (looks more professional) and if your not already use this website https://www.w3schools.com

Comment: How do I remove .html from my links? I've been trying to do that for a while now... Sorry I'm not very good at this

Comment: https://vimeo.com/user24572931/review/441815395/0a41442177 this is a link to a screen recording of the button issue